# Inheritance in constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

My question largely relates to this one [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

So, say we have Animal that is a super interface of Cat and Dog. We also have a abstract class Litter such that

```
public abstract class Litter{

    public Litter(Collection<Animal> animals){}
}
```

And then we naturally have a concrete class KittyLitter

```
public class KittyLitter extends Litter{

    public KittyLitter(Collection<Cat> animals) {
        super(animals);
    }
}
```

...and puppy litter.

Naturally, we want to limit all Animal in a KittyLitter to just Cat. Why doesnt Java allow us to do this? Then, also lets say we add another method --

```
public abstract void addCub(Animal animal);
```

and concrete implementation in KittyLitter of

```
@Override
public void addCub(Animal cat) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

At this point this breaks logic and allows us to insert a Dog into a KittyLitter which makes no sense. Any ideas as to why Java does these things to us? Also, if KittyLitter constructor can be changed to accept a List, why does the type argument behave differently? Can anyone explain why this is so?

EDIT: this is really not about constructors, but also any method that overrides.

Comment: [**Type erasure**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: What you have there, the constructors, will not compile.

Comment: Yeah, can you clarify your question? Are you asking why Java doesn't let us do what you have in your constructors?

Comment: Precisely. The way I have it in my question will not compile. Specifically the KittyLitter constructor wont compile

Comment: Generic types in Java are non-reified, erased, and invariant.  For these reasons, Collection<Cat> is -NOT- a subtype of Collection<Animal>, so your code will not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the superclass generic, using a [bounded type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) to say what kind of animals the litter can hold:

```
public abstract class Litter<T extends Animal> {  // <-- type bound
  public Litter(Collection<T> animals) { /* ... */ }
  public void addCub(T cub) { /* ... */ }
}

public class KittyLitter extends Litter<Cat> {
  public KittyLitter(Collection<Cat> cats) {
    super(cats);
  }
}
```

This allows the subclass to limit what kind of animals the inherited superclass methods will accept, by specifying a type for T.  `KittyLitter`'s `addCub` method takes a `Cat` argument, not an `Animal`.  And `PuppyLitter`'s `addCub` will take a `Dog`.

Comment: My question 'why does Java not allow Collection<Cat> in KittyLitter constructor as opposed to Collection<Animal>' as still unanswered, but as per Wyzards' answer there is an alternate mechanism to narrow down argument types. Accepting answer -- his solution is effectively, well, effective.

Comment: That part was answered by the previous question you linked to.  A `Collection<Animal>` allows any kind of animal, including dogs.  A `Collection<Cat>`, obviously, doesn't.  If a method wants a container that can hold any kind of animal, you can't give it one that's limited to a certain type.  After all, there could be code in that method that adds dogs and cats and rhinoceroses to the collection you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are not overriding super constructors and you can declare them with any parameters you like. You can declare non-overriding methods with any parameters as well.

Overridden methods must be able to be called as if you call the parent directly so they cannot narrow parameter types. When `Litter` says it can be called with any `Animal` then it must be able to be called with any `Animal`.

Comment: I dont think thats accurate. You can declare KittyLitter constructor with (ArrayList<Animal> animals) arguments, and the super class Litter has arguments of (Collection<Animal> animals). We're narrowing own from Collection all the way to ArrayList.